# PID制御のコーディングについて

Tags: python, python3, numpy, sympy

Pythonで制御工学を学んでいます。そこで、このコードに疑問点があります。

サンプル方式
MVn = MVn-1 + ΔMVn
ΔMVn = Kp(en-en-1) + Ki en + Kd((en-en-1) - (en-1-en-2))

＃ただし
MVn、MVn-1:今回、前回操作量　　ΔMVn:今回操作量差分
en,en-1,en-2：今回、前回、前々回の偏差　とする。

というPID制御のモデルのような式なのですが、比例項に疑問があります。

比例項は、”現在”の偏差にゲインをかけたものですよね？なぜ、前回の偏差が引き算されるのでしょうか？

ご説明よろしくお願いします。

参考
・PythonでPID制御をやってみる
https://qiita.com/BIG_LARGE_STONE/items/4f8af62b3edc4a03c4a5

・モータのPID制御法
http://www.picfun.com/motor05.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

「操作量」について誤解があるような？

操作量とは操作できるものの量（＝現在値）

- 弁を開閉する場合、操作量とは弁開度（０点から何ステップ回した）
- 自動車を走らせるとき、操作量とはアクセル開度
- モーターを回すとき (ブラシレス DC モータなら) インバータの出力周波数

実際に制御する上で必要なのは「操作量の差分」っスよね。

- 追加で何ステップ開ける閉じる
- アクセル板の末端高さで何ミリ踏み込む戻す
- 周波数をいくつ下げる上げる

だから紹介されたページにも「今回の操作量＝前回の操作量＋今回の操作量差分」とちゃんとありますよね。欲しいのは「今回の操作量差分＝今回の操作量－前回の操作量」となれば操作量の漸化式から提示の式となります。

Comment: なるほど。つまりこの式　ΔMVn = Kp(en-en-1) + Ki en + Kd((en-en-1) - (en-1-en-2))　は、MVn = MVn-1 + ΔMVn　を移行したものにすぎないということですね？それならば、比例項と微分項は納得しました。しかし新たな疑問が出てきました。積分項は、どうすれば出てきますか？

Comment: わかったような気がします。積分なので、Kp(en+en-1+...e1 )- Kp(en-1+en-2+...e1)ということですね？